# How does slideToggle work with bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm making a page, where I need a slideToggle list with roughly five items inside, and I'm unsure how to proceed. For this project, I've tried using Bootstrap and JQuery

Below is my whole code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list").click(function() {
    $(".item").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #252525;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  width: 90%;
}

#container {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 1%;
}

.list {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'roboto';
}

.item {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="list">
        Choose item<i class="icon-down-big"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="item">This should slide down on click on Purple div</div>
      <div class="item">This should slide down on click on Purple div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought that on clicking `<div class="list">` I would see `<div class="item">`, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've been trying to change classes to id, but it doesn't help. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you need to open a single toggle with all the list element inside?

Comment: Hi your Question s not clear. what you want to toggle when click on button?

Comment: Hi, i want to make <div class="list"> clickable, so then i would see <div class="item"> that are set by default hidden

Comment: It looks like its working fine. You click "Choose Item" and you want to see the divs "This should slide down on click on Purple div". Still kind of unclear what you are asking for. Should there be another nested click?

Comment: I have changed my browser and it was fine, it seems it had some troubles with this.
Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0):

Try using the slideToggle Method:

**jQuery slideToggle() Method**

Toggle between slideUp() and slideDown() for all

elements:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

it has the following parameters:

**speed**

Optional. Specifies the speed of the slide effect. Default value is 400 milliseconds Possible values:

- milliseconds
- "slow"
- "fast"

**easing**

Optional. Specifies the speed of the element in different points of the animation. Default value is "swing" Possible values:

- "swing" - moves slower at the beginning/end, but faster in the middle
- "linear" - moves in a constant speed

**Tip**: More easing functions are available in external plugins

**callback**

Optional. A function to be executed after the slideToggle() method is completed

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp